# error oracle query on older php version

Tags: php, oracle, iis, oracle11g

i have this script on PHP :

```
$sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM PROJECT.ACTIVITY 
        WHERE START_DATE = '03-02-2012' 
";
$stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

it's work on my other machine but failed on another,
failed message:
**Warning: oci_fetch_array() [function.oci-fetch-array]: ORA-01843: not a valid month in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\info.php on line 31**

```
work machine:
- win 7 prof x64
- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.2.6
- Oracle 11g

work machine:
- win 7 prof x64
- Apache 2.2.11
- PHP 5.2.6
- Oracle 11g

failed machine:
- win 2003 server x64
- IIS 6.0
- PHP 5.1.4
- Oracle 11g
```

these three machines get oracle db from one oracle server.

Comment: i just want to explain, the oracle db is not inside the each machines, but i have one oracle server where each machine get the data ..

Comment: i get one clue, in the failed machine i have to use statement: 
START_DATE = '03-FEB-12' instead of START_DATE = '03-02-2012' why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm) parameter on the database and ensure it matches to whatever date you're passing in the PHP part. If not, use a [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) and convert it to the required format.

Comment: is NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set in php/webserver? since i use one oracle server but has different format different php version .

Comment: @kreamik it's set in db server. Differing PHP versions maybe the reason - they might be sending it in a different manner - I'm not a PHP person though

Answer (score 0):

If START_DATE is of datatype DATE your statement should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECT.ACTIVITY WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('03-02-2012','DD-MM-YYYY');
```